# How to verify authenticity of free unsecured (public) wifi station?

Tags: security, networking

When in a location with free wifi, how can we use `netstat` to verify the network is what it claims to be? i.e. to look up the underlying address/IP and cross validate that against a list of known IPs for the particular provider?

#### Example

At an airport one may find something like `Free Google Wifi Station`, with everything matching the style of Google, but how can we use `netstat` to confirm that the network indeed belongs to Google?

Answer (score 1):

Netstat is typically used to monitor incoming/outcoming connections. If you note that your machine is communicating with an unexpected service/machine (or there is too much traffic from and to the latter , it might be an hint of non authenticity of the WiFi station.
But it still depends on multiple factors.

Comment: Thanks. Specifically, I will attempt to look for some unique identifier (one that cannot be spoofed) using netstat, and cross check against some public info on the wifi provider’s documentation/website. Thus, making sure the network is the authentic one and not someone imitating it by simply having a wifi network name that sounds vaguely genuine but could actually be anyone’s (personal) network

Comment: @stevec: I guess you're referring to a possible Evil Twin attack scenario. Here you can find out some more info about https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/85138/how-would-you-detect-an-evil-twin-attack-especially-in-a-new-environment